# Using handler with autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is it possible to change path when autocomplete function is triggered or to change path syntax inside `.cshtml` file (view)?

To give you an example, here is my code:

Textbox for autocomplete:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="formFilters" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="visitor" placeholder="pick a visitor" class="form-control" style="margin-right:20px;" />           
    </div>
```

Autocomplete script:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#visitor').autocomplete({
         source: 'VisitorHandler.ashx'
     });
  });
</script>
```

VisitorHandler.ashx.cs :

```
namespace Visitor_Management
{
    public class VisitorHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            List<string> VisitorNames = new List<string>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VisitorSQLCommand"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                //setting up query and parameters                  

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //writing inside List
                }
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(VisitorNames));
        }    
    }
}
```

My question is: How to change a path on .autocomplete or how to put `VisitorHandler.ashx` in the current path with route and is there any other way to do this same logic on different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relative URL to source use root-relative URL (/VisitorHandler.ashx):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#visitor').autocomplete({
        source: '/VisitorHandler.ashx'
    });
});
```

Note: Consider replacing the handler with a controller when in MVC world. You're mixing 2 different technologies.

Comment: Love it when / is missing...regarding your note, how would I do it with a controller? a separate one or a method inside a current one?

Comment: @MarkoPetričević I'd say for small projects it's OK to create an action method in the same controller that produced the view. Define sensible route for the action and `return Json(VisitorNames);`. Use `Url.Action(...)`  in your view to get the URL of your autocompletion resource.